# Where to find a java library to read vcard files?

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

I need a java library to read vcard files (vcf).

Comment: Stackoverflow is a web site for QUESTIONS. Please rephrase it as a question. Nonetheless, it's not a real question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [search for Java and vcard](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+vcard) yields quite a few results.

In particular there's the [Mime-Dir-j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-dir-j/) which is no longer under active development, but may be all you need, and [vcard4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcard4j) which seems to have been dormant for even longer (last release 2003!).

Comment: I already found those projects and was hoping for something else in active development, but I'll try them anyway, thank you all.

Comment: As a quick FYI, Mime-Dir-j seems to include the vcard4j code but also has more recent bug fixes applied.

Answer (score 22):

[ez-vcard](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) supports versions 2.1, 3.0, and 4.0 of the vCard standard, as well as XML-encoded vCards ("xCard" standard), HTML-encoded vCards ("hCard" microformat), and JSON-encoded vCards ("jCard" standard).

https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

To read a vCard file, use the `Ezvcard.parse()` method.  Then, call the various getter methods on the returned `VCard` object to retrieve the vCard data fields.

```
File file = new File("my-vcard.vcf");
VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(file).first();
System.out.println("Name: " + vcard.getFormattedName().getValue());
System.out.println("Email: " + vcard.getEmails().get(0).getValue());
```

Comment: Hey, seems like best .vcf parser so far, but lets say I have .vcf that has email home, email work and email other. Can you please show detailed example of how would I store different types of emails (home, other, work) to String emailHome, emailWork, emailOther? vcard.getEmails().get(0).getValue(); always gives first, but how to know if that is home email or work email or other email?

Comment: @Marko Call the "getTypes()" method on each email object to get its list of "type" parameters.  You can then check to see if its type is "home" or "work": email.getTypes().contains(EmailTypeParameter.HOME);

Comment: +1 active development

Answer (score 8):

[Cardme](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cardme) seems to be the best vcard library around with active development and there is even a wiki site up.

Check the project [homepage](https://github.com/george-haddad/cardme).

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used it yet (about to try it out), but this looks promising.

http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=VCard

Answer (score 1):

I found this API that might do the trick: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-dir-j/

Answer (score 0):

Try Google, Yahoo, whatever and find http://vcard4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Well, just in case you want to use a mobile phone, JSR75 does it right out of the box:

javax.microedition.pim.PIM.fromSerialFormat is specified as supporting vCard 3.0