# How to parse contact .vcf file programmatically?

Tags: android

Is there any way to parse contact VCF file programmatically ?

I able to create .vcf from contacts but unable to parse in my code.

Comment: Have a Look it https://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar thanks :-) ! is it not possible to read it without using any external library .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672704/where-to-find-a-java-library-to-read-vcard-files. And there is no harm parsing it with external library.

Comment: @Darpan thanks ! but I am restricted to use any external lib :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of ez-vCard, a external library, I am able to parse vcf file. But still not able to parse it using any Android built-in API.

```
    String backup_file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/contact_backup.vcf";
    File backup_file = new File(backup_file_path);

    List<VCard> vcard;
    try {
        vcard = Ezvcard.parse(backup_file).all();
        for (VCard vCard2 : vcard) {
            //System.out.println("Name: "+ vCard2.getFormattedName().getValue());
            //System.out.println("Email: "+ vCard2.getEmails().get(0).getValue());
            //System.out.println("Phone No: "+ vCard2.getTelephoneNumbers().get(0));

           //Get list of phone numbers
            List<Telephone> telePhoneNumbers = vCard2.getTelephoneNumbers();

            for (int i = 0; i < telePhoneNumbers.size(); i++) {
             System.out.println("Phone No: "+ telePhoneNumbers.get(i).getText());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just download ezvcard library and add it to project and use following function to read vcf file. I have checked it and working fine for me.

```
public void readVCF(){   
try{
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/temp.vcf");
        List<VCard> vcards = Ezvcard.parse(file).all();
        for (VCard vcard : vcards){
          System.out.println("Name: " + vcard.getFormattedName().getValue());
          System.out.println("Telephone numbers:");
          for (Telephone tel : vcard.getTelephoneNumbers()){
            System.out.println(tel.getTypes() + ": " + tel.getText());
          }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}}
```