# Create contacts using .vcf file

Tags: android-contacts

I understand, Contacts can be created from a vcf file on device by importing it from "Contacts" application

How to do the same from an application by  programming

Comment: aren't you the same Manju that asked this same question 2 days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853260/creating-contact-programmitcally-using-vcf-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse contact .vcf file programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776910/how-to-parse-contact-vcf-file-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows you how to do that: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html